# Oracle before delete trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have two tables

**army**

- name VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
- number_of_soliders INTEGER

**soldier**

- soldier_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
- army_name VARCHAR(50) REFERENCES army(name)

Now, I need to create trigger, which would work as ON DELETE CASCADE. The problem is, that I have already existing trigger for soldier, which automatically updates number_of_soldiers for his army and if i just put there ON DELETE CASCADE, it will result in a error, because when I delete the army, the trigger can't reference the number_of_soliders back.

**So the task is to create trigger, which will delete all soldiers of the army before the army itself is deleted.** I have tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_DELETE_SOLDIER
    BEFORE DELETE ON army
        FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM soldier WHERE army_name = :old.name;
END;
```

Hovewer, this results in an error table is mutating, trigger may not see it on table **operates**, M:N table which references Soldier ID (ON DELETE CASCADE) and Weapon ID. However, the trigger does not touch this table, nor the second one for updating number_of_soldiers.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: "if i just put there ON DELETE CASCADE, it will result in a error" - what error does that get? Trying to maintain a count of children on the parent table is awkward anyway - simultaneous transactions could get confused. It's better to just calculate that count when you query, possibly via a view.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the tip, eventually I replaced all the triggers with views. :)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest to use `on delete cascade` with your foreign keys on your tables instead of solving this with a trigger?

```
alter table soldier 
add constraint fk_soldier
  foreign key (army_name)
  references army(name)
  on delete cascade
;
```

If you already use `on delete cascade` on this constraint, then maybe you forgot it on the `weapon_id`, which you also mention in your question.

NOTE 1: please consider using a numerical primary key for your army table and the foreign key. You are up to big trouble if you want to change the army name and need to update all child tables as well.

NOTE 2: you don't have to store the number of soldiers in your army table because you can let the database calculate that. Do you have a specific reason to store it redundantly?

Comment: I already tried on delete cascade, but it does not work. I have a trigger on soldier table, which automatically updates the number_of_soldiers attribute in army table with AFTER INSERT OR DELETE. And there is the problem - if you combine this trigger with ON DELETE CASCADE, 1. step - army is deleted, 2. cascading to soldiers 3. trigger is activated, tries to reference the army which was deleted, but fails. That's why I have to solve this with trigger. Regarding PK's, this is a school project and the attributes can't be artificial.

Comment: Answer for 2: yeah that is reasonable, I actually did not think about that :P

Answer (score 0):

Storing and maintaining `number_of_soldiers` in the parent table is awkward and can break if multiple sessions insert/delete soldiers for the same army at the same time. If you don't do that then you don't need soldier-level triggers to update the army table, and can go back to `ON CASCADE DELETE` without a trigger on the army table either. The number of soldiers for each army can be found by joining the tables:

```
select a.name, count(s.soldier_id) as number_of_soldiers
from army a
left join soldier s on s.army_name = a.name
group by a.name;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5d06ab1f628ce0c246a4cd03a31b0b22). (That query can of course be stored as a view; which could be materialized if necessary.)

But for the sake argument, if you are stuck with the table column maintenance and need the trigger to clean up, an option is to selectively bypass the soldier-level trigger, using a `when` clause and an environment context value.

For example, you could add calls to `dbms_application_info.set_client_info` (or module, or action - whatever make most sense), with a value that makes sense for you to indicate why the soldier-level trigger should not fire; something like (with a not-very-helpful value):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_DELETE_SOLDIER
    BEFORE DELETE ON army
        FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO('CASCADING');
    DELETE FROM soldier WHERE army_name = :old.name;
    DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO(null);
END;
/
```

Then in the soldier-level trigger test for that value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_decrement_army
BEFORE DELETE ON soldier
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (sys_context('userenv', 'client_info') is null
   OR sys_context('userenv', 'client_info') != 'CASCADING')
BEGIN
  UPDATE army SET number_of_soliders = number_of_soliders - 1
  WHERE name = :old.army_name;
END;
/
```

If the context value has been set by the army-level trigger, then soldier-level trigger won't run because the `when` condition is not met. Otherwise it will still  run and decrement the soldier count.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7fe19a9680c4a487d12f93f024ad9acb)

But this is still not recommended...

Comment: Yeah I eventually replaced all triggers with views and finally no bugs at all. :)